# Tramp FTP cant connect. tramp-file-name-handler: Host name must not match method "ftp"

Tags: dired, tramp, remote, ftp

I am trying to connect ftp using tramp I am using

`C-x C-f`

`/ftp:username@subdomain.hostname.com`

I get an error message in the mini buffer: 
`tramp-file-name-handler: Host name must not match method "ftp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, it misses the trailing colon. Try `C-x C-f /ftp:username@subdomain.hostname.com:`